# U disk is prohibited under non-administrator on windows10 , how to access U disk by C#?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I'm writing a program to access the U disk under non-administrator on Windows 10, but the normal user's U disk is prohibited and the program cannot run as an administrator.

Under ordinary users, how does C#'s program perform normal U disk access?

Comment: By having administrator access... if the u-disk can only be accesed with administrator privileges, then in order to access the u-disk you need administrator privliges... what are you asking exactly? Because it seems you already know the answer

Comment: The security restrictions are there for a reason. BTW you should probably explain what you mean by `U disk`. USB? A network share mapped to the `U:` drive? In any case if a domain policy prevents users from accessing external drives you *can't* bypass it.

Comment: To put it another way, even if this was possible, it would *no longer* be possible by the next Patch Tuesday. Such a huge security breach would be fixed ASAP

Comment: Require admin rights in your application's manifest.  Problem solved.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you think you need access to an external drive? Why don't you contact the domain admin and explain what you want to do?